# how to pass multiple files to zip for zipping

Tags: command-line, zip

Say I have a list of files a.txt, b.txt, c.txt, is it possible to pass it to zip command as arguments and make it zip it in one file say a.zip?

Answer (score 66, accepted):

Sure. The [man page of `zip`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/zip) says you can specify `[file ...]` on the command line. This [notation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9725675/is-there-a-standard-format-for-command-line-shell-help-text) says you can specify multiple files separated by spaces, like this:

```
zip a.zip a.txt b.txt c.txt
```

You can also utilize [pathname expansion](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/expansion/globs). The shell will replace wildcards used in the filename with *all* matching filenames. Example:

```
zip a.zip *.txt
```